# C# Extend ListView data with List

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, mono

I have ListView name as "lstQueue". I use WinForms.

I want ListView and List are related, when ever ListView do:

1. add item
2. remove specific item
3. clear item
4. move item above
5. move item below

List also follow, mean 1:1 data relation. For example:

1. ListView move item, item inside List also move (either up or down)
2. ListView delete item, item inside List also get deleted.
3. ListView clear item, item inside List also get cleared.

Here my existing code:

```
public class Data
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public bool C;
    public int D;
}
```

In Form1 (main):

```
    List<Data> FF = new List<Data>();

    private void btnQueueAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem QueueList = new ListViewItem("0");
        QueueList.SubItems.Add("1");
        lstQueue.Items.Add(QueueList);

        // Sample data
        Data Temp = new Data()
        {
            A = "GG",
            B = "OK",
            C = true,
            D = 10
        };
        FF.Add(Temp);
    }
    private void btnQueueRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lstQueue.SelectedItems)
            item.Remove();

        // List
    }
    private void btnQueueClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstQueue.Items.Clear();
        FF.Clear();
    }
    private void btnQueueUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (lstQueue.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ListViewItem selected = lstQueue.SelectedItems[0];
                int indx = selected.Index;
                int totl = lstQueue.Items.Count;

                if (indx == 0)
                {
                    lstQueue.Items.Remove(selected);
                    lstQueue.Items.Insert(totl - 1, selected);
                }
                else
                {
                    lstQueue.Items.Remove(selected);
                    lstQueue.Items.Insert(indx - 1, selected);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        // List
    }
    private void btnQueueDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (lstQueue.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ListViewItem selected = lstQueue.SelectedItems[0];
                int indx = selected.Index;
                int totl = lstQueue.Items.Count;

                if (indx == totl - 1)
                {
                    lstQueue.Items.Remove(selected);
                    lstQueue.Items.Insert(0, selected);
                }
                else
                {
                    lstQueue.Items.Remove(selected);
                    lstQueue.Items.Insert(indx + 1, selected);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        // List
    }
```

Comment: I can't tell what is working and what isn't working from your question.  What specifically is broken?  What is it supposed to do?  What does it do instead?

Comment: When ListView item move up, List<T> item also move up, ListView item move down, Lits<T> also move down.

Comment: Edit your question, don't reply here. =)